# Java Logging: console vs. file output

Tags: java, logging

I have a question about `java.util.Logger`. 
I set the file handler and changed the format like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TotalLog");
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("log/total.%g.log", 5242880, 20, true);
fh.setFormatter(new Formatter() {

  @Override
  public String format(LogRecord record) {
    return new Date(record.getMillis()) + " " + record.getLevel() + ": " + record.getMessage() + "\n";
  }
});

logger.addHandler(fh);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "****************************************");
```

The problem is the formatter affects the log file. But the console is not showing messages in this format. Also, code like this works in console, but does not work in file.

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0} user folders registered.", userfolders.size());
```

Which means on console its printing: `4 user folders registered.`
But on file: `{0} user folders registered.`

How do I solve these problems?

**EDIT**:
Ok here is the solution, I found a link that is showing how to access the default console handler of logger: [logging in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392604/logging-in-java)

So instead of creating an anonymous class, I created a new class named `LogFormatter`:

```
public class LogFormatter extends Formatter {
  @Override
  public String format(LogRecord record) {
    return new Date(record.getMillis()) + " " + record.getLevel() + ": " + record.getMessage() + "\n";
  }
}
```

And changed the code a little bit:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TotalLog");
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("log/total.%g.log", 5242880, 20, true);
fh.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
logger.addHandler(fh);
logger.getParent().getHandlers()[0].setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
logger.log(Level.INFO, "****************************************");
```

Still, I can't figure out how to do parameterized logging. Meanwhile I replaced the code by:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, userfolders.size() + " user folders registered.");
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do you write code for this? You can configure a formatting pattern (even programmatically) to achieve the same result. As it is, you probably broke the replacement logic.

Comment: The default log looks this
  DATE CLASS : METHOD
  LEVEL: MESSAGE
However i need this format
  DATE LEVEL: MESSAGE

Comment: Some examples for format strings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29  But java.util.Logging is quite a pain. I recommend looking at SLF4J instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `formatMessage` from the `Formatter` class (or copy and adjust it for your needs), e.g.:

```
public class LogFormatter extends Formatter {
  @Override
  public String format(LogRecord record) {
    return new Date(record.getMillis()) + " " + record.getLevel() + ": " + super.formatMessage(record) + "\n";
  }
}
```

See comment for `format` method on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html:

> public abstract String format(LogRecord record)
>
> Format the given log record and return the formatted string.
>
> The resulting formatted String will normally include a localized and
>   formatted version of the LogRecord's message field. It is recommended
>   to use the formatMessage(java.util.logging.LogRecord) convenience
>   method to localize and format the message field.